# Debugging UI updates on the main thread, iPhone, Activity Indicator not spinning

Tags: iphone

so I know you are supposed to do your updates on the main thread.  I am using Apple's code for writing our database do the documents directory:

```
// Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory.
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookdb.sql"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
        return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookdb.sql"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

I do

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
```

I do not see my activity indicator.  If I comment out `[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];`, I do see my activity indicator.  Is there a way to debug this to see what is happening and why I don't see my spinning indicator?  Thanks.

Comment: you are supposed to do **UI** updates on the main thread.  if you have a significant amount of non-UI work, you can do that in the background with performSelectorInBackground, or you can use GCD and blocks, to either schedule a block a little later on the UI thread, or in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of context, it is hard to say, but I assume that you want the activity indicator to represent the `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` operation ongoing. Assuming that the `[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded]` was called from your main thread, you can do something like this:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

Comment: the brackets and parenthesis aren't closed correctly. there is a missing ) and ;

Comment: True, thanks! I guess I have grown too comfortable using IDEs such as Xcode and Eclipse :)